# Is virtual final method better than non-virtual one in a root class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an abstract class that is the root of hierarchy of classes. That root class have a method with some trivial implementation and it seems there is no need to change that implementation anywhere anytime.

Making that method non-virtual is fine, but there is a chance that some subclass will reimplement it by accident. Is virtual final method a better solution in that case?

Comment: What harm could overriding the non-virtual method do?

Comment: _"there is no need to change that implementation anywhere anytime"_ That's for the author of any derived classes to decide.

Comment: What do you mean "some subclass will reimplement it by accident"? Code doesn't really just spawn from the ether you know.

Comment: If you can demonstrate that it may prevent a class of potential error and all other things being equal then I really don't see why not go with the virtual final.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just the opposite.  To be used as a base class, a class must be designed as a base class, and there will always be limits on what the derived class can do, in order that its invariants hold.  The author of the derived class must respect the rules laid down by the base class.

Comment: @user2079303, It's not overriding any more, it's hiding. Usually leads into errors in polymorphic classes.

Comment: I'm not so sure but I tend to think that virtual+final is a good solution but it bears the cost of virtual calls. However, I guess, a good compiler/optimizer can devirtualize the call and then you pay no cost at all.

Comment: `virtual final` only catches hiding when the function signatures match.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to declare the method as `virtual... final`, you will make all users pay the runtime cost of virtual dispatch in order to protect a small number of users who might accidentally *hide* the base class' function.

Since one of the guiding principles in C++ is "you [don't](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1356) [pay for](http://herbsutter.com/2012/12/03/perspective-why-c-is-not-back/) what [you don't](http://www.stroustrup.com/slashdot_interview.html) use," I would say it is better to leave the function non-virtual, and let derivers be responsible if they hide the function.

Comment: I mostly agree, but I'm not sure the additional runtime cost is certain.

Answer (score 0):

If a subclass re implements it by mistake it wont matter if the object is being access from the base class. The decision comes down to polymorphism, do you want the method to be polymorphic or not?, if you do, make it virtual, if you dont, then dont.